# Get the list of all available coordinates by current coordinates

Tags: php, geolocation, distance, latitude-longitude

I am working on a project in which I have to find persons near me. I am able to get current coordinates. The problem is that I can't get the list of coordinates between radius of given kilometre. I got the script from Internet:

```
function twopoints_on_earth($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo,  $longitudeTo) 
  { 
       $long1 = deg2rad($longitudeFrom); 
       $long2 = deg2rad($longitudeTo); 
       $lat1 = deg2rad($latitudeFrom); 
       $lat2 = deg2rad($latitudeTo); 
          
       //Haversine Formula 
       $dlong = $long2 - $long1; 
       $dlati = $lat2 - $lat1; 
          
       $val = pow(sin($dlati/2),2)+cos($lat1)*cos($lat2)*pow(sin($dlong/2),2); 
          
       $res = 2 * asin(sqrt($val)); 
          
       $radius = 3958.756; 
          
       return ($res*$radius); 
  } 
  
  // latitude and longitude of Two Points 
  $latitudeFrom = 19.017656 ; 
  $longitudeFrom = 72.856178; 
  $latitudeTo = 40.7127; 
  $longitudeTo = -74.0059; 
     
  // Distance between Mumbai and New York 
  print_r(twopoints_on_earth( $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom,  
                $latitudeTo,  $longitudeTo).' '.'miles');
```